# simple regex not working

Tags: java, regex

this is the regex I wrote

```
String regex="(start_)(u[0-9]+)(p[0-9]+).";
```

I want to match with "start_u12p16". here u is for user_id and p for project_id.
User_id here is 12 and project_id is 16, which will change each time....I want to match the incoming string if its in that format...
that is start_u[any number]p[any number]

```
if(str.matches(regex)==true){retVal= true;}
```

Its so simple regex, till yesterday it was working but dont know why its not working now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a dot at the end of your regex, which means that any string with a single digit after the p will not match properly (for example, start_u12p5).  Remove it and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

The following modification makes the expression to work as expected:

```
String regex="start_u[0-9]+p[0-9]+";
String id = "start_u12p16";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher =  pattern.matcher(id);
System.out.println(matcher.matches());
```

Answer (score 1):

The dot at the end of your pattern ("any char") takes one digit from the end. Not only the single digit does not match any longer as @jgm says, but also the third group is probably wrongly captured:

```
  String regex="(start_)(u[0-9]+)(p[0-9]+).";
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
  Matcher m = p.matcher("start_u12p17");
  System.out.println(m.matches());
  System.out.println(m.group(3));
```

Results

```
      true
      p1
```